# How to save data in expressjs/session NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, request

I have 3 files : app.js, index.js(routes), Users.js(controller)

Once my user is loggedIn (verification done between POST information and DB) i want to save data in a session using expressjs/session.

Here is the declaration of my session in the app.js :

```
var session = require('express-session');

    app.use(session({
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        secret: 'trolololo'
    }));
```

Here are my routes :

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    Users.login(req, res);
});

router.get('/getSessionInfos', function(req,res,next){
    console.log(req.session);
});
```

And here is the controller for the login :

```
login : function(req, res){
        var formEmail = req.body.email;
        var formPassword = req.body.password;

        User.findOne({ where: {email: formEmail} }).then(function(user) {
            if(user){
              if (user.password == formPassword){
                  console.log('User connected');
                  req.session.email = formEmail;
                  req.session.password = formPassword;
                  console.log(req.session);
                  res.status(200).send('User Authentified');
              }else{
                  res.status(401).send('Invalid Password');
              }
          }else{
              res.status(401).send('Username');
          }
        });
    },
```

The Login works I get the 200 status and my console.log in the login function displays a function with my infos. But when i try fetching my session from the /getSessionInfos URL it is empty... Please send help

Comment: is that the whole code in `/getSessionInfos` ? you only output to console and you don't return anything

Comment: Well i assumed that from the expressjs/session documentation that session is always fetched via a req.session.something and as i said i get the session object but it is empty. But yes this is all there is in /getSessionInfos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Code seems correct only some changes

```
app.use(session({
secret : 'yourSecret',
resave : false,
saveUninitialized : false,
}));
```

Not forget to login first as you are storing the session value over there and then it will surely display the object with the email and password key .
Let me know if You face any problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know you did not ask this, but i will state it either way, sessions are not recommended in node any more, json web tokens are pretty much the at the throne.In essence it's a signed piece of data in JSON format. Because it's signed the recipient can verify its authenticity. Because it's JSON it weights very little.

In very simple terms, JWT are cool because you don't need to keep session data on the server in order to authenticate the user.

> - The user calls authentication service, usually sending username and
>     password.
>
>   - The authentication service responds with a signed JWT, which says who
>       the user is.
>   - The user requests access to a secured service sending the token back.
>   - Security layer checks the signature on the token and if it's genuine
>       the access is granted.

You can use jwt-simple in npm.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Your Code seems correct only some changes

app.use(session({
secret : 'yourSecret',`enter code here`
resave : false,
saveUninitialized : false,
}));



//in login details save the session by using "req.session.save();" 
//then try to run it work properly


login : function(req, res){
        var formEmail = req.body.email;
        var formPassword = req.body.password;

        User.findOne({ where: {email: formEmail} }).then(function(user) {
            if(user){
              if (user.password == formPassword){
                  console.log('User connected');
                  req.session.email = formEmail;
                  req.session.password = formPassword;
                   req.session.save();
                  console.log(req.session);
                  res.status(200).send('User Authentified');
              }else{
                  res.status(401).send('Invalid Password');
              }
          }else{
              res.status(401).send('Username');
          }
        });
    },
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!